# Nested loops through an array of objects in a Vue Instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've created this large Array of square objects in my Vue Instance, that look like this:

```
new Vue({
el: '#application',
data:
{
    title : 'Conways Game of Life',
    squaresClassVar : 'squares',
    userColor : '#453BCC',
    startBool : true,
    squaresFromServer:[],
    squares:
    [
        { row: 0, column: 0, color:'#D3D3D3'},
        { row: 0, column: 1, color:'#D3D3D3'},
        { row: 0, column: 2, color:'#D3D3D3'},
        { row: 0, column: 3, color:'#D3D3D3'},
        { row: 0, column: 4, color:'#D3D3D3'},
        { row: 0, column: 5, color:'#D3D3D3'},
        ...
     ]
```

Each square is tied to an actual square canvas in my HTML and CSS. When I make a request to the server I'm populating the `squaresFromServer[]` Array which gets populated just like the squares array. I'm trying to loop through both arrays to update the colors of the squares that are sent from the server.

the current algorithm looks like this:

```
this.squares.forEach(indexLocalSquares => {
    this.squaresFromServer.forEach(indexServerSquares => {
        if(indexLocalSquares.row == indexServerSquares.row  && indexLocalSquares.column == indexServerSquares.column )
        {
            console.log('entered')
            indexLocalSquares.color = indexServerSquares.color 
        }
        else
        {
            indexLocalSquares.color = '#D3D3D3'
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is `indexLocalSquares.color` is not actually updating with the color that is sent from the server's square.

Does anyone know how I might loop through both of these arrays so that I could update the color of the squares Array with the squares that are sent from the server.

In most other languages I would simply do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0, i <= squares.length - 1, i++)
{
    for(int j = 0, j <= squaresFromServer.length - 1, j++)
    {
        if(squares[i].row == squaresFromServer[j].row && squares[i].column == squaresFromServer[j].column)
        {
            squares[i].color == squaresFromServer[j].color
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that [`data` must be a function](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function)

Comment: @Derek data must be a function when defining a component, it can be a simple object when initializing a Vue instance.

Comment: @EmileBergeron would you mind pointing me to a place in the documentation where I might find that

Comment: @Derek any example in the doc really, they all use the simpler syntax of instantiating Vue with `new Vue(/*...*/)` with a data object. And the API entry on the [`data` option](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data) is clear about this.

Comment: @EmileBergeron the API description reads more as a warning than anything else

Comment: @Derek it's just a restriction and it makes sense when you think about components being reused and instance being created once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174283/discussion-between-derek-and-emile-bergeron).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the color in different iterations of the cycle. First set all colors to your default color and then update only those colors which are present in the server response

```
this.squares.forEach(indexLocalSquares => {
            indexLocalSquares.color = '#D3D3D3'
});

this.squares.forEach(indexLocalSquares => {
    this.squaresFromServer.forEach(indexServerSquares => {
        if(indexLocalSquares.row == indexServerSquares.row  && indexLocalSquares.column == indexServerSquares.column )
        {
            indexLocalSquares.color = indexServerSquares.color 
            console.log(indexLocalSquares);
        }
    });
});
```

Please note that nested iteration is of O(rows * cols) complexity.

Comment: Thank you, that makes so much sense now from reading your answer. I feel kinda sheepish for doing that. But I struggled for a quite a long time and it made me question my syntax using Vue.  Thanks again.